# Insert data from datatable to MySql table

Tags: mysql, vb.net

My code inserts data from datatable to Mysql table, however process takes long time. Is there anyway i could modify my method to make "One shoot insert" of my datable values? Would be nice also to have it within transaction. Thanks.

```
 Dim result As Boolean = False
        Dim MysqlConn As MySqlConnection
        MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection()
        MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=duo;Uid=root;Pwd=pass1;"
        Using con As New MySqlConnection(MysqlConn.ConnectionString)

            For Each r As DataRow In _dtSir.Rows

                Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO " & _serializer.GetTableName(_reportId) & " (SR, IDcol, System) 
                                                VALUES (@SR, @IDcol, @System)", con)

                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SR", r("SR#"))
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDcol", CInt(r("ID")))
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@System", r("System"))

                    If Not con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                        con.Open()
                    End If

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    result = True
                End Using
            Next

        End Using

        Return result
    End Function
```

Comment: Since `_dtSir` appears to be a datatable, there is no need for any of that code.  Use a DataAdapter to update/insert all new rows at once.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to see if faster:

```
Public Function test()
    Dim result As Boolean = False
    Using con As New MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=duo;Uid=root;Pwd=pass1;")
        con.Open()
        For Each row As DataRow In_dtSir.Rows
        Using cmd = con.CreateCommand()
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO " & _serializer.GetTableName(_reportId) & " (SR, IDcol, System) VALUES ('" & row("SR#") & "', '" & CInt(row("ID")) & "','" & row("System") & "'", con)
                cmd.Connection = con
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                result = True
            End Using
        Next
        con.Close()
        SqlConnection.ClearPool(con)
    End Using
    Return result
End Function
```

There might be a few things to tweak since I never used the **MySqlConnection**

Comment: unfortunetly it isn;t ;/

Comment: around 50000, there should be any other option rather than looping every row.

Comment: Thats really a lot... Maybe you could try to just add the row to the database at the moment it is added to you DGV that way you dont need a huge loop and just upload to the database on the go.

Comment: There has to be other way to do it quickly Still looking for it.

Comment: @Dino try like i said as soon the row added to the DGV add it to the database

Comment: cannot do it like this because once there is load time datatable is ready.

Comment: Then just up the amount or memory the mysql server is allocated. if have good hardware mysql server can easily run 500 000+ per second you could also try implementing multi thread in your app to run multiple connections and inserts at the same time

Comment: @currently it tooks around 5 min for 11000 rows.

Comment: Like I said check the allocated memory of your MySQL Server and also think maybe of implementing a Multi thread.